# Explanation for 感 in 感叹词

Tags: difference

While beginning to learn Chinese, I encounter 叹词 (tàncí) and 感叹词 (gǎntàncí) for the equivalent meaning of [interjection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interjection) in English. I would like to know why the symbol 感 (gǎn) meaning 'to feel' is added and if there is a resulting difference in meaning. In other words, is it proper grammar or necessary to include the 感 symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is virtually no difference. Perhaps `嘆詞` is more concise than `感嘆詞`.

However, `嘆/叹` itself is seldom used alone in modern Chinese. Modern Chinese tends to use bisyllabic words. So we say `感嘆` (to interject), `讚嘆` (to praise), `嘆息` (to sigh) to 'augment' or 'specify' the meaning of `嘆/叹`.

`嘆詞` is already bisyllabic; but it still doesn't hurt to say it as `感嘆詞`.

`感` bears the concept of 'to feel'. You interject after you experienced an emotion. It confers neutrality and generality to the word `感嘆` (compare with `讚嘆`, which is fairly positive).

Comment: Xièxiè L Parker